# Can we split a polygon in half (vertex-wise) by a diagonal, but with a constant maximum difference?

Tags: discrete-geometry, polygons

This is a followup to my last question - [Can we prove that simple polygons can always be split in half (vertex-wise) by diagonals?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342954/can-we-prove-that-simple-polygons-can-always-be-split-in-half-vertex-wise-by-d)

Is there a constant natural number K for which the following is true:

> For any simple polygon with more than 3 vertices there always exists a
>   diagonal which:
>
> - is inside the polygon
> - doesn't intersect with any edges
> - splits the polygon in two polygons in such a way that the difference between their vertex counts is smaller than K

Comment: No, by a slight modification of the example answering the previous question: just place most of the vertices evenly between A and A' and the other two pairs.  Gerhard "Imagine Using A Circular Saw Blade" Paseman, 2019.10.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, by modifying the answer to the previous question.

We start with an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and a larger equilateral triangle $A'B'C'$ with the same center and parallel edges. We consider the hexagon $AA'BB'CC'$.

[image]

Instead of this hexagon, we replace $A'$ with a sequence of $2K$ points all clustered near the original $A'$. Then we do the same for $B'$ and $C'$, so that the new polygon has $6K+3$ vertices.

Any division of this polygon into nearly equal halves will have to divide up one the clusters of $2K$ vertices. But starting from the cluster of vertices near $A'$, the only diagonals that avoid edges either stay within the cluster or go to $B$, so no diagonals can avoid the edges and provide the desired split.

Comment: What's the minimum difference between halves achievable in this polygon?

Comment: A diagonal from $A$ to $B$ has $2K$ vertices on one side, $4K+1$ on the other, so the minimum difference (which I think is what you meant to say) is $2K+1$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to say. I changed my comment accordingly.